# Arba'a Vachamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposedly the three-year cycle of reading the five books of Moses divided them into 154 sections (all told). I have no good source for this, though.

Comment: This is mentioned in the endnotes to the Koren Chumash.

Answer (score 2):

Megilas Eicha has 154 Pesukim.

Comment: =22×7. (Sufficiently many characters for a comment, and then some.)

Answer (score 0):

> Jerusalem appears in the Jewish Bible
>   669 times and **Zion 154 times**, or
>   823 times in all. The Christian Bible
>   mentions Jerusalem 154 times and Zion
>   7 times. In contrast, the columnist
>   Moshe Kohn notes, Jerusalem and Zion
>   appear as frequently in the Qur'an "as
>   they do in the Hindu Bhagavad-Gita,
>   the Taoist Tao-Te Ching, the Buddhist
>   Dhamapada and the Zoroastrian Zend
>   Avesta"—which is to say, not once.

http://www.danielpipes.org/84/the-muslim-claim-to-jerusalem